# How to cache browsing history and bandwidth utilization on squid

Tags: linux, squid

I want to know how to monitor the users browsing history and bandwidth utilized by individual IP addresses on Squid proxy. How can i get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

squid maintains a thorough access log, typically in /var/log/squid, aptly named `access.log`.

There is a utility named `sarg`, the `Squid Analysis Report Generator`, that can be used to parse this log, gather useful statistics from it, and generate a friendly and convenient Web-browsable report that you can examine with any Web browser.

In its simplest form, you invoke `sarg` with the name of the log file you wish to examine, like this:

```
sarg /var/log/squid/access.log
```

**For bandwidth utilization::**

The basic concept is to set up per-host (class 3) delay pools in `squid.conf`, then set each of them to the maximum amount of bandwidth I want to allow per user per day. Then, set the "fill" rate to be that maximum amount of bandwidth divided by one day's worth of time, so each delay pool will fill completely in one day.

Comment: Hi, I had tried the above and worked like a charm...It was in deed helpful.. 
Still I need little more help that when ever i execute the command for preparing report it reads the whole access log and gives me the report which is being a kind of duplication... Now i would like to know how i can run this command on every shutdown of the server and start a new access log on system start..

Comment: Can you tell the corresponding method for seeing browsing history on windows?